# Imported WMS and WMTS did not overlap in ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, wms, wmts

I've created WMS and WMTS of the same city then imported them to ArcMap via service capabilities copy link location but they did not overlap.

P.S. the one at the top of the layers is the tif itself and perfectly overlaps with WMS.

What's wrong ?

[image: wms]

[image: in here transparent one is wms, other is wmts]